# Kendo tree in kendo grid - collapse issue

Tags: kendo-grid, kendo-treeview

I am trying to get kendo tree in kendo grid.

I could able to achieve to get the data, but not the tree functionality.

below is the link for same

http://dojo.telerik.com/oDakE

can anyone help me why the expand and collapse is not working

Comment: What have you tried? Is there an event handler defined? Any errors on the console? When you create the tree outside of the grid, does it work? Have you compared the tree outside the grid to the tree inside the grid to see if they are the same?

Comment: No event handler, it is just a fetch from the API, and also no error's in the API at all.. yes it is working fine outside the grid, i compared all the data is also same. no issues with code. I think i am missing something but not sure where i went wrong

Comment: Perhaps if you can provide a sample of your code, it might help. Or is the link your code?

Comment: Just realized a possible issue.  Your treeview does not exist when the document loads, so no eventhandlers associated with the treeview will ever fire.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried kendoTreeList, it accepts a json sort of like a treeview but you assign a parent id to each node, and displays as a grid.